# ASP.NET - Show a pop up when navigate away from the page and On click of OK go to a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a user control on the page. I want to show a confirm box when I try to navigate away from the page(e.g. I clicked on a link which navigates to a different URL). In the confirm box, I want the ability to Navigate to a specific page on the click of OK and on the click of CANCEL do the intended action.

Following code is not working for me:

```
window.onunload = function ()

                {
                    if(confirm('You must make elections for the next plan year (Open Enrollment). Click OK to review that event and submit your elections.'))
                    {
                        alert('OK');  
                        window.location.assign('http://www.google.com');                            return false;
                    }
                }
```

Ideas?

Comment: Which page in you do above code?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to preserve onunload function before modifying it 
follow :

```
var existingUnload = window.onunload;
window.onunload = function ()
{
   if(confirm())
    {
      // your custome logic 
       return false;
     }
   else
   {
     existingUnload();
    }
```

}